# Boot to Windows 7 install CD

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my 2006 Mac Pro. I know the Windows 7 install CD is good, but I get a bizarre message during the boot process, after which nothing happens.

```
  .2
Select CD-ROM boot type:
```

None of my keys do anything when this comes up, and but it appears to be waiting for input. I tried to fix this by installing `rEFInd`, but I get an error message there as well. What do I do to get Windows 7 installed?

**Update:**

I have been working on this all morning, with absolutely no luck. I have a working install CD and just want to install Windows 7 OVER Ubuntu, so I can install Ubuntu as the second operating system as suggested by the Ubuntu developers. Basically, I want to wipe everything and start fresh with Windows 7 and go from there. What do I do?

My investigation would seem to indicate that the uEFI system is the problem. When I tried to fix this by installing rEFInd, I learned that it must be done from an OS X partition, which I never want to have again. Basically, I need to completely remove everything Apple-made, including their bootloader, from my computer for this to work, otherwise the Apple tech makes it impossible to install properly. What can I do?

**Update 2**

I just realized that I should have mentioned my problem with OS X. I cannot use OS X because my GPU is unsupported, so I get a black screen with white bars around *some* GUI elements. It is almost entirely impossible to see what is going on, so I cannot use it.

Comment: Make sure your boot options are correctly set up in BIOS. Select the removable media you want to boot from and make it the first priority, or manually select it in your boot options on startup. If you get the same message I believe the input it is waiting for is either `1` or `2`. Might also be useful to know what motherboard you have.

Comment: @jessenorton I'm pretty sure the Intel Macs don't have BIOS, and I have been unable to find any information on my motherboard.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you're right. As far as I'm aware the best way to install Windows 7 on a mac pro is to use bootcamp. Do you still have OSX installed?

Comment: @jessenorton No, I'm afraid I removed that a while back. If it helps, I removed it using the Ubuntu install CD's "Install over OS X" option, whatever that was called.

Comment: Just curious because I've not tried to install Windows 7 like this. How are you accessing the Windows 7? Through grub?

Comment: @jessenorton I suppose I could try that, but I have been trying to boot from the CD by holding the "c" key. Isn't that what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I don't own a mac and the only time I've installed Windows 7 on one I was running OSX so I just use bootcamp.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot boot into OS X. My GPU is not an Apple-supported model, so I just get a black screen (with white bars around GUI elements). It I could, I would use Bootcamp, as it actually boots to the CD.